# How can I ensure that relative links are saved as absolute URLs in the output file?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter

I need to develop a web links scraper program in Python that extracts all of the unique web links that point out to other web pages from the HTML code of the "Current Estimates" web link, both from the "US Census Bureau" website (see web link below) and outside that domain, and that populates them in a comma-separated values (CSV) file as absolute uniform resource indicators (URIs).

I use the code below in Jupyter Notebook and it seems it generates a CSV but part of my code is generating a double https:// on the already absolute links when it should just be adding it to the relative links.

`http:https://www.census.gov/data/training-workshops.html`

`http:https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sis.html`

I need a better code that can change the relative links to absolute I believe the `full_url = urljoin(url, link.get("href"))` should be doing this, but something is incorrect.

How can I ensure that relative links are saved as absolute URLs in the output file?

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

import csv

from urllib.parse import urljoin

import re


url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'

r = requests.get(url)


raw_html = r.text

print(r.text)


soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())


for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):

  full_url = urljoin(url, link.get("href"))

  print(link.get('href'))


links_set = set()

for link in soup.find_all(href=re.compile('a')):

  print(link.get('href'))


for item in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile(r'html')):

  links_set.add(item.get('href'))

  links = [x[:1]=='http' and x or 'http:'+x for x in links_set]


with open("C996FinalAssignment.csv", "w") as csv_file:

  writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter="\n")

  writer.writerow(links)
```

Comment: You need to address the line `links = [x[:1]=='http' and x or 'http:'+x for x in links_set]`. If you are having trouble writing it as a list comprehension, just iterate over `links_set` and adjust those that need adjusting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import requests
import csv
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'
r = requests.get(url)
raw_html = r.text
print(r.text)
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(raw_html)
lstA = doc.listA(url=url) # It will help you turn relative links into absolute links
links = [a.url for a in lstA]
with open("C996FinalAssignment.csv", "w") as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter="\n")
  writer.writerow(links)
```